# Javascript - How do I show a string of text when my referrer equals x

Tags: javascript

I haven't found a good example of this yet out here so I'd love it anyone can help!

I'm looking to use Javascript to display a string of text only when my referrer is equal to a particular url& path. (Of course if there's a better more efficient way, I'm all ears!)

**Example:**

- If referring URL is exactly "https://example.com/thepage"
- Then show html text at the top of the page: "Thank you for coming from the page"
- If they came from anywhere else, then ignore and do not display the text

*Note*: I do not want to show this via a js 'alert'

Thanks for the help everyone!
Joe

Answer (score 1):

You can create a div element (assign it id or class) on HTML and leave it blank then on js you can target it and assign it a value when your condition returns true

```
// target the element
let TargetedElem = document.getElementById("ELEM_ID"); 

// target Current Path
let path = window.location.pathname;

// if you wanna target the whole URL then`
let URL = window.location.href;

if(path == "YOUR Path") {
  TargetedElem.innerText = "YOUR MESSAGE";
}else {
  TargetedElem.innerText = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Husnain!
Curious though.  It seems that  window.location.pathname is targeting my current page.  I'm needing to show text if my previous page contains a particular path.

Comment: for that you can use "document.referrer".